# Как настроить Tor через OpenVPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, tor

Можно ли добиться выхода в сеть Tor через подключение OpenVPN?

Сейчас имеется сервер на Ubuntu с запущенным сервером OpenVPN. Хотелось бы иметь возможность получать выход на адреса `*.onion`.

Подскажите, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: **[TOR plus VPN](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorPlusVPN)** Так же есть схема работы **Tor через VPN** и **VPN через Tor** на википедии по ТОРу

Answer (score 0):

Перенаправьте трафик с VPN в Tor. Получится, что когда вы будете подключаться к VPN, ваш трафик уйдет в Tor. На выходе так же останется IP одной из выходной ноды, и вы сможете без проблем посещать сайты `.onion`.